# Returning null with String matching alg

Tags: java, string, algorithm

am implementing a String matching algorithm for a username database. My method takes an existing Username database and a new username that the person wants and it checks to see if the username is taken. if it is taken the method is supposed to return the username with a number that isn't taken in the database.

Example:

"Justin","Justin1", "Justin2", "Justin3"

Enter "Justin"

return: "Justin4" since Justin and Justin with the numbers 1 thru 3 are already taken.

In my code sample below, newMember returns null and I don't know why. It should return "justin4"

```
public class UserName {

 static String newMember(String[] existingNames, String newName){
    boolean found = false;
    boolean match = false;
    String otherName = null;

    for(int i = 0; i < existingNames.length;i++){
        if(existingNames[i].equals(newName)){
            found = true;
            break;
        }

    }
    if(found){
        for(int x = 1; x < 100 ; x++){
            for(int i = 0; i < existingNames.length;i++){
                if(existingNames[i].equals(newName + x))
                    match = true;

            }
            if(!match)
                otherName = newName + x;
        }
                    // It returns NULL instead of "Justin4". Its as if otherName doesn't
                    // change after its initialization.
        return otherName;

    } else return newName;
}

public static void main(String[] args){

    String[] userNames = new String[4];
    userNames[0] = "Justin1";
    userNames[1] = "Justin2";
    userNames[2] = "Justin3";
    userNames[3] = "Justin";


    System.out.println( newMember(userNames, "Justin"));
    }
}
```

Comment: The people voting to close this as a duplicate should pay attention; the other thread is about the same project but asks a different question at an earlier stage. That problem was solved, and a new question is entirely appropriate for a new problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset `match` to `false` at the start of each `x` loop iteration. Otherwise, it will match an earlier number, and `match` will be stuck at true for the rest of the `x` iterations. You'll never see that it doesn't match for a larger `x`.

You should also break out of the `x` loop when you find a name, otherwise you will keep overwriting `otherName` with a larger `x`.

You may wish to break out of the `i` loop (although you don't need to) for efficiency; no sense checking the rest if you already know there's a match.

Comment: When I break out of the x loop by calling break right after otherName = newName + x, i get a compiler error that claims the x++ in the for loop is dead code? is there a better place to call break? ur right if I don't call break it just returns Justin99.

Comment: NeverMind it was just a bracket issue. it works fine now. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're never resetting your `match` variable. So if it is set to `true` in the first run, it is never set to `false` again, and `if(!match) otherName = newName + x;` never happens. Change this

```
if(existingNames[i].equals(newName + x))
    match = true;
```

to

```
match = existingNames[i].equals(newName + x);
```

Comment: Almost. You need to break from the inner loop when you find a match if you do it that way. Consider the case where it matches `existingNames[2]` but not `existingNames[3]`, for example.

Comment: I was wondering, is there a better way to write this algorithm? When I say better I mean more efficient. and No my database is not and SQL database it is just and Array of strings given to me

Comment: @user2510809 You could store the names in a `HashSet<String>`; then you have `contains()` which simplifies your code quite a bit, and a hash table lookup can be done very quickly compared to brute force searching a list. You can use a `LinkedHashSet<String>` if you need to preserve insertion order.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if case sensitivity is also important for you, in which case you should be careful to use equalsIgnoreCase method instead of equals in your case, just for safety. Also if your username database is a SQL database, I suggest doing this check against the database itself with a query, it should be somewhat more efficient.
Otherwise yes, reset your match variable.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to **break of the outer for loop in the if(found)**, once you have the newName, along with **resetting the boolean to false**.

Or it will just get concatenated to a very long userName.